# What is the best UX of account linking in Google Home App

Tags: deep-linking, user-experience, google-home, google-smart-home, account-linking

I'm developing my smart home device.
For now, it doesn't have a native app but only a web client.
My home-actions work well, but I'm worried about the complexity of adding a new device in the google home app.

According to add new device user have to:

1. Open Home app
2. Click + button
3. Click "Set up device"
4. Click "Have something already set up"
5. Find my application in the list

And only then starts the process of the user linking.

I think that should be an easier way to link users, for example, deep-link to "user linking" in-home app, but I cannot find one.

Can someone explain the best user experience of account linking in Google Home App, for both mobile application and web application?

Answer (score 0):

For native application, Smart Home documentation now feature a section about [App Flip](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/account-linking#oauth-based_app_flip) which allow you to "deep-link" to your native application to complete the account linking process.